# Deserialize interface to specific type with jackson without JsonSubTypes

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have a project A where I have an interface like this:

```java
interface MyInterface extends Serializable { }
```

In another project B I have a class that implements that interface:

```java
@Data
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    private String someProp;
}
```

Now I would like to tell jackson that I want to deserialize all appearances of `MyInterface` as `MyClass`. I know it is normally possible to use `JsonSubTypes` but in this case Project A does not know Project B.

Is there maybe a way to get the default deserializer for a type? Then I could just do something like this:

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(MyInterface.class, DefaultDeserializerForMyClass);
```

I know that I could write custom deserializers that do exactly the same, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add `@JsonDeserialize` on `MyClass` and use `ObjectMapper.addMixIn()` with `MyInterface` as target.

> public ObjectMapper addMixIn(Class target,
> Class mixinSource)
>
> Method to use for adding mix-in annotations to use for augmenting
> specified class or interface. All annotations from mixinSource are
> taken to override annotations that target (or its supertypes) has.
>
> target - Class (or interface) whose annotations to effectively override
> mixinSource - Class (or interface) whose annotations are to be "added" to target's annotations, overriding as necessary

for example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

@JsonDeserialize(as = MyClass.class)
class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
        private String someProp;

        /* getters and setters */
}
```

---

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper()
{
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.addMixIn(MyInterface.class, MyClass.class);
        return om;
}
```

---

```
@PostMapping
public String foo(@RequestBody MyInterface bar)
{
        if (bar instanceof MyClass) {
                MyClass baz = (MyClass)bar;
                System.out.println(baz.getSomeProp());
                return "world"
        }
        return "goodbye"
}
```

---

```
$ curl -X POST -d '{"someProp": "hello"}' -H "content-type: application/json" localhost:8080
world
```

and server correctly prints:

```
hello
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for!